# C# adding methods and checking to see if numbers have been added

Tags: c#, methods, int

have a small program im playing with. need to make sure it checks if number, if not loop untill their is a number on each input and create a main method and calculator method any help?

code is here /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
        int num1;
        int num2;
        string operand;
        float answer;
        string text1;




        ////enter first number ////
        Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
        text1 = Console.ReadLine();

        // if number not integer then fail ////
        bool res = int.TryParse(text1, out num1);
        if (!res)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" FAIL");
            ////enter first number ////
            Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
            text1 = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {

        }



        //// enter operand ////
        Console.Write("Please enter an operand (+, -, /, *): ");
        operand = Console.ReadLine();



        // enter second number //
        Console.Write("Please enter the second number: ");
        text1 = Console.ReadLine();

        // if number not integer then fail //
        bool eff = int.TryParse(text1, out num2);
        if (!eff)
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" FAIL");
                // enter second number //
                Console.Write("Please enter the second number: ");
                text1 = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            while (eff == true);
        {

        }
        // converts number to integer ///


        // makes operand answers from each number ////
        switch (operand)
        {
            case "-":
                answer = num1 - num2;
                break;
            case "+":
                answer = num1 + num2;
                break;
            case "/":
                answer = num1 / num2;
                break;
            case "*":
                answer = num1 * num2;
                break;
            default:
                answer = 0;
                break;
        }

        /// converts numbers to string using operand and writes final line ///
        Console.WriteLine(num1.ToString() + " " + operand + " " + num2.ToString() + " =                   
        "+ answer.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
        }

        }


        }

        }

        /// converts numbers to string using operand and writes final line ///
        Console.WriteLine(num1.ToString() + " " + operand + " " + num2.ToString() + " = 
        " + answer.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is all you need and you are using a Console App, you can use:

```
        int num1;
        int num2;
        string operand = string.Empty;
        float answer;
        string text1;

        ////enter first number ////
        Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
        text1 = Console.ReadLine();

        // if number not integer then fail ////
        bool res = int.TryParse(text1, out num1);
        while (!res)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" FAIL");
            ////enter first number ////
            Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
            text1 = Console.ReadLine();
            res = int.TryParse(text1, out num1);
        }

        //// enter operand ////
        while (operand == string.Empty || operand.Length > 1 || !(new char[] { '+', '-', '*', '/' }).Contains(char.Parse(operand)))
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter an operand (+, -, /, *): ");
            operand = Console.ReadLine();
        }


        // enter second number //
        Console.Write("Please enter the second number: ");
        text1 = Console.ReadLine();

        // if number not integer then fail //
        bool eff = int.TryParse(text1, out num2);
        while (!eff)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" FAIL");
            // enter second number //
            Console.Write("Please enter the second number: ");
            text1 = Console.ReadLine();
            eff = int.TryParse(text1, out num2);

        }
        // converts number to integer ///


        // makes operand answers from each number ////
        switch (operand)
        {
            case "-":
                answer = num1 - num2;
                break;
            case "+":
                answer = num1 + num2;
                break;
            case "/":
                if (num2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Divide By Zero Error");
                    return;
                }
                answer = num1 / num2;
                break;
            case "*":
                answer = num1 * num2;
                break;
            default:
                answer = 0;
                break;
        }

        /// converts numbers to string using operand and writes final line ///
        Console.WriteLine(num1.ToString() + " " + operand + " " + num2.ToString() + " =  "+ answer.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Why do you need to create a separate method for something so simple. And I found this too simple to be asked, so just asking if this is what was required? You could have struggled a bit more and written this yourself. There is nothing trivial in this. I am just assuming that you are new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

the problem appears to be with the handling of "eff" and "res". If the user keys a non integer value the first time they're asked it doesn't matter what they answer the second time as num1 and num2 aren't populated with the value. Fix that and the code appears to work.

As entering the values appears to be doing the same thing but with a slightly different prompt you should move this into a seperate function, something like this:

```
    static int GetNumberFromUser(string order)
    {
        string userText = String.Empty;
        int result;

        Console.Write("Please enter {0} number: ", order);
        userText = Console.ReadLine();

        while (!int.TryParse(userText, out result))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FAILED");
            Console.Write("Please enter {0} number: ", order);
            userText = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

You would then call it by calling

```
    num1 = GetNumberFromUser("first");
    num2 = GetNumberFromUser("second");
```

This function takes care of converting to a number and keeps asking until the user keys in a valid value.

The "Calculator" method would just be copied and pasting the switch you have into a seperate method:

```
    static float Calculator(int num1, string operand, int num2)
    {
        switch (operand)
        {
            case "-":
                return num1 - num2;
            case "+":
                return num1 + num2;
            case "/":
                return num1 / num2;
            case "*":
                return num1 * num2;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
```

Called using

```
        answer = Calculator(num1, operand, num2);
```

Whilst I'm at it, the result line is difficult to read, I'd go for something like this

```
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} = {3}", num1, operand, num2, answer);
```